# Print entire word in If loop

Tags: python

I wrote the following code :

```
lst=["Terribly Tricky"] 
for word in lst:
    for letter in word[-6:]:
        print(letter)
```

And I was excpecting python to print "Tricky" but it returned the following :

```
T
r
i
c
k
y
```

How can I get it to print it like this :

```
Tricky
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: Just eliminate the inner loop, and replace it with `print(word[-6:])`

Comment: `print(word[-6:])`, but "word" is a poor name for something that's not a word, but multiple words (in this example "Terribly Tricky")

Comment: Hint: try `for word in lst: print(word)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Others have suggested viable solutions. But, if you want to go with nested for loops, here is something you can try.

```
    lst=["Terribly Tricky"] 
    for word in lst:
        s = ""
        for letter in word[-6:]:
            s += letter
        print s
```

If you want to print the word but are okay with spaces between letters, just put a comma after the print. It will print on the same line and add a space between prints - useful when printing list items.

```
    for word in lst:
        for letter in word[-6:]:
            print (letter),
```

This prints `T r i c k y`

*Note: please re-indent the code block if using the python code.*

Answer (score 1):

So, what you can do is just split the string inside *lst*. In your case, splitting will create a list of strings. And then you can print the string that you want.

```
lst=["Terribly Tricky"]

for word in lst:
    words = word.split(' ')
print (words[1])
```

This will print "Tricky" in one line.